# pluck based on common attribute (rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table Followership, in which every record has attributes `user_id` and `follower_id`.

I can do something like this:

```
Followership.limit(10).pluck('user_id, follower_id)
```

But this will give me result like this `[[1,A][2,B],[3,C],[4,A],[1,B][2,D]]`

I want to convert the above array in such a way that all arrays with same `user_ids` should be merged in following form `[user_id, FOLLOWER_ID(S)]`

i.e;

```
[[1,[A,B]][2,[B,D]],[3,C],[4,A]]
```

Here `user_id = 1` has two followers `A,B` and `user_id = 2` has two followers `B,D`

How to do this?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html - it has a lot of useful methods. In particular, `group_by` which you can use here.

Comment: Yes @SergioTulentsev is right . you need to use group by .

Answer (score 3):

As [pointed out by Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144417/pluck-based-on-common-attribute-rails/45146941#comment77257746_45144417), you could use `group_by` with the array that you get after `pluck`, for example:

```
arr = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[4,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'D']]

a.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }
#=> [[1, ["A", "B"]], [2, ["B", "D"]], [3, ["C"]], [4, ["A"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
a = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[4,'A'],[1,'B'][2,'D']]
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
a.inject(h) { |sum, t| sum[t[0]] << t[1]; sum}.to_a
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what `group_by` does under the hood.

Comment: Yes. but `&:` confuses most novice developers so I represented little simpler solution.